# Kotlin Why Changing Local var also updating companion object's var

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mutablelist

If I `clear()` my local list (`mList`) it also clearing `companion`'s Mutablelist (`list`)
Why this happening explanation's are welcome :)

I've a class with `companion` like this :

```
class Data {
    companion object {
        var list:MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    }
}
```

If I create my local list something like this :

```
fun main() {
   // some dummy data
   Data.list.add("Lion") 
   Data.list.add("Cat")
   Data.list.add("Dog")
   Data.list.add("Cheetah")

   // my local mList
   val mList = Data.list

   println("Before Clearing : mList = $mList\n list = ${Data.list}")
   mList.clear()
   println("After Clearing : mList = $mList\n list = ${Data.list}")
}
```

**OutPut**

```bash
Before Clearing : mList = [Lion, Cat, Dog, Cheetah]
 list = [Lion, Cat, Dog, Cheetah]
After Clearing : mList = []
 list = []
```

As You can see in output if I `clear()` local `mList` it is clearing `companion`'s list Why it is ?

if I do this same with some other things like `double` it is not happening like this example -

```
// same Data class's
...
  var pi = 3.14
...
```

If change local `mPi` it doesn't change `pi` :

```
var mPi = Data.pi
println("Before Assigning to New value mPi =  $mPi and pi = ${Data.pi}") 
mPi = 319.12
println("After Assigning to New value mPi =  $mPi and pi = ${Data.pi}")
```

2nd Output

```bash
Before Assigning to New value mPi =  3.14 and pi = 3.14
After Assigning to New value mPi =  319.12 and pi = 3.14
```

Link of [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/rmO-R-um_)

Why it is happening? I'd like to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand what is going on here you need to know how values are saved in memory. All objects that are created using the `new` keyword (not needed in Kotlin), are stored in heap memory whereas all primitive data types are in stack memory.

Consider the following code

```
val list: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
```

What is happening here is that a new object of `ArrayList` is being created in the heap. The variable `list` can be considered as a box which holds the location where the actual object is created. You can imagine the variable holding a value of `0x7800abd12`.

Now what happens, when you create a new variable and assign the one that you created above.

```
val newList = list
```

Here, you assigned whatever value the variable `list` had to the variable `newList`. What this did was in fact save the memory address `0x7800abd12` in the variable `newList`. Remember, the value is the location where the actual list is created. Now, if the user accesses either `list` or `newList`, they will be taken to the object at the given memory address. Since both variables have the same address, any change made to either of the two variables will reflect for both of them.

But why doesn't this behaviour reflect when we are using primitive data types. Remember, I mentioned that primitive data types are stored on the stack rather than heap. Consider this example

```
val pi = 3.142
```

In this case, the variable `pi` actually holds the value `3.142` rather than a memory location. Now, when you assign it  to another variable, the new variable also holds the value rather than a memory location.

```
val newPi = pi
```

Here `newPi` holds the value `3.142`. If you change `newPi` to some other value, it will only update the variable `newPi` and won't update the variable `pi`.

In order to learn more about this you can check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: thank you I'd looking for something like this thanks +1

Comment: This explanation about primitives  isn’t really correct. It has nothing to do with primitives vs classes and stack vs heap, and has everything to do with whether you are changing what a variable is pointing at vs mutating a mutable class instance. In Kotlin you can think of all primitives as classes just like non-primitives. They behave just like any immutable class.

Answer (score 1):

You compared changing the contents of a list with changing the value of a variable, which are not the same thing. In your example, `mPi` is first assigned to point at the value of `Data.pi` and then it’s changed to point at some other Double. You aren’t doing anything to modify the Double itself, only what the local variable `mPi` is pointing to.

When you do `val newList = Data.list`, you are declaring the variable to point to the same list instance as in Data. Then you modify the *contents* of that same list. Since both variables are pointing at the same instance, you will observe the same changes if you inspect the instance via either variable.  Notice you did not reassign the variable’s value using `newList =` like you did in the `pi` example, which is why these are not analogous actions.

In short, with the pi example, you have two Double instances and were switching between them by changing the value of a variable. With the list example, you have only one  MutableList instance that you are internally mutating.

Notably, primitive type classes are all immutable so there’s no way you could modify their contents even if you wanted to. They don’t have functions you can call on them to change the value they represent. In Kotlin you rarely have to think about the distinction between primitive classes and other classes unless you’re optimizing code performance.